# Насколько — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

**...зависит от того, насколько установленный размер превысит...**
Верно ли написано «насколько»?

Answer (score 2):

Написано, вероятно, верно, но, видимо, возможно и раздельное написание. От контекста многое зависит.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже было сказано, всё верно:

**...зависит от того, насколько установленный размер превысит...**

1) Вот, к примеру,  реальный текст

Сумма Штрафа за нарушение знака «Ограничение скорости» довольно внушительная. Она зависит от того, **насколько** была превышена скорость и от повторности нарушения: Превышение установленной скорости **на величину больше 20,** но не более 40 км/ч — водителя имеют право оштрафовать на 500 рублей.
Источник: http://pravo-auto.com/zona-dejstviya-znaka-ogranichenie-skorosti/

Здесь речь идет о конкретных цифрах, но ***насколько*** (= в какой степени) ***превысит*** написано слитно.

2) **А вот пример из учебника (в качестве контекста)**

За сутки молодой бамбук может вырасти на 86,4 см. **На сколько** он вырастет за секунду?

Это неполное предложение, единица измерения не указана, но подразумевается: ***на сколько сантиметров (миллиметров).***

Comment: Ну, приводить в пример ПДД и подобные документы в качестве эталона – это, знаете ли... Там тоже вполне возможно раздельное написание, оно ни в коем случае не будет ошибкой. Оно даже предпочтительнее.

Comment: Приведите другие источники в качестве примера, определите частотность написания вариантов, тогда и можно будет говорить о том, что предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 1):

Да, всё верно. ***Насколько*** здесь значит ***в какой степени*** и пишется слитно. Если бы были какие-то единицы в конце, тогда писалось бы раздельно, например ***на сколько рублей/зарплат***.

Comment: *На сколько метр больше сантиметра?* Где здесь единицы в конце?

Comment: Я же не сказал, что в любом случае должны быть единицы в конце, а рассматривал только эту фразу!